# NSScanner scanDouble UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsscanner

I'm using `NSScanner` to scan a string and extract a double from it. Here's my sandboxed code to try and solve the problem

```
let string = "maxage=1234567890"
let scanner2 = NSScanner(string: string)
scanner2.scanUpToString("=", intoString: nil)
scanner2.scanString("=", intoString: nil)
let maxage2:UnsafeMutablePointer<Double> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>()
scanner.scanDouble(maxage2)
print(scanner2.scanLocation)
print(maxage2)
```

it prints:

```
7
0x0000000000000000
```

So the first two calls to consume the first part of the string work, but then scanning a double isn't working.

I've seen other solutions that look like this:

```
var double = 0.0
scanner.scanDouble(&double)
```

But that doesn't seem to work in Swift anymore. Maybe it did in an earlier version?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Still works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you accidentally had a typo there by using `scanner.scanDouble` instead of `scanner2.scanDouble`?

This works for me:

```
let string = "maxage=1234567890"
let scanner2 = NSScanner(string: string)
scanner2.scanUpToString("=", intoString: nil)
scanner2.scanString("=", intoString: nil)
var aDoubleNumber = 0.0
scanner2.scanDouble(&aDoubleNumber)
print(scanner2.scanLocation)
print(aDoubleNumber)
```

Comment: Yes! that works. Funny I've tried so many things. I tried basically this, and I realize now what I had done was defined 'let aDoubleNumber' so I would get a compile error '& used with non-inout argument of type UnsageMutablePointer<Double>' so I was confused thinking I couldn't pass it a reference with &.